# Why is Groovy not catching my instanceof?

Tags: groovy, instanceof

In the following code:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    String str

    if(str instanceof String) {
        println "'str' is a String!"
    } else {
        println "I have absolutely no idea what 'str' is."
    }
}
```

The statement "*I have absolutely no idea what 'str' is.*" is what prints. **Why, and what can I do to make Groovy see that `str` is a String (besides making the String non-null)?**

Comment: The "besides making the String non-null" part of your question means that the answer is that there is no way to do what you are asking about.  You can't interrogate a local variable reference at runtime and ask what its declared type is.  The language doesn't account for that because there is no good reason to want to do that.  You already know the declared type at compile time.  There is no reason to interrogate a local variable reference and ask its declared type.  The answer I posted blow addresses related questions.

Comment: Hopefully to clarify, when I say there is no reason to interrogate a local variable reference and ask its declared type I mean specifically that.  Don't mistake that for the idea that you might not want to interrogate an object on the heap and know its type, but your question specifically asserts that you aren't interested in doing that with the "besides making the String non-null" qualifier.

Comment: Why is it that you would like to interrogate the declared type of a local variable reference at runtime?

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown - I am looking to use instanceof after every single variable declaration to make sure that the runtime does in fact provide me with the right type that I just asked for. Sort of my spin on "defensive coding".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `str` is null, which is not a `String`.

The instanceof keyword interrogates the object that the reference points to, not the reference type.

**EDIT**

Try this...

```
static void main(args) {
    String str = 'King Crimson Rocks!'

    if(str instanceof String) {
        println "'str' is a String!"
    } else {
        println "I have absolutely no idea what 'str' is."
    }
}
```

Comment: Also OPs code does not even compile in java; in groovy it's a `NullObject` -- *Confusion will be my epitaph*

Comment: @cfrick "Also OPs code does not even compile in java" - It is Groovy code, not Java code.  The fact that it won't compile as Java code or as C++ or any other language doesn't seem relevant.  Have I misunderstood the original question or your comment?

Comment: I see that you edited your comment after I asked, but I am still not sure why it is relevant than the code won't compile as Java.

Comment: I think not.  But if java throws up with `error: variable str might not have been initialized` it might be more evidence, that it can't be done.  and it was a good way to throw in some King Crimson reference.